# Hash inside YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I want to include a hash and list inside a YAML file that I'm parsing with the following command:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")
```

My YAML file looks like this:

```
feeds: [{:url => 'http://www.google.com', :label => 'default'}]
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
How would I go about achieving such a thing?

Thanks,
Yuval

---

EDIT: Sorry, guys. I'm still unclear about how to do this and I suspect it is in part due to my somewhat vague phrasing. I asked a better-phrased, more broad question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034435/storing-information-inside-yaml). Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can mark it up like this

```
feeds:
 - 
  url: 'http://www.google.com'
  label: 'default'
```

Note the spacing is important here. "-" must be indented by a single space (not a tab), and followed by a single space. And `url` & `label` must be indented by two spaces (not tabs either).

Additionally this might be helpful: http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html

Answer (score 16):

Ceilingfish's answer is maybe technically correct, but he recommends to use a white space at the end of a line. This is prone to errors and is not a good practice!

This is how I would do it:

Create a settings.yaml file with the following contents:

```
---
feeds:
  :url: 'http://www.google.com'
  :label: 'default'
```

This will create the following hash after the YAML file has been loaded:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> YAML.load_file('settings.yaml')
=> {"feeds"=>{:url=>"http://www.google.com", :label=>"default"}}
irb(main):003:0>
```

In this example, I also use symbols since this seems to be the preferred way of storing Ruby keys in Ruby.

Comment: But would this really produce what he requested? I think he wants "feeds" to be a list of hashes, not just a hash. I'm kind of in the same spot, and also don't like the fragile approach that requires trailing space. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Will post my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Old question, but since I was in a similar spot... Like Jasper pointed out, Ceilingfish's answer is correct. But you can also do

```
feeds:
 - url: 'http://www.google.com'
   label: 'default'
```

to avoid having to rely on trailing whitespace after the dash.