# turn `YAML::load_file` into proper hash

Tags: ruby, yaml

So I have this test script

```
require 'yaml'

hashYaml = YAML::load_file("./monFichier.yaml")
puts "hashYaml : " 
puts hashYaml

hashManuel = {enonce: "ma question", titre: "mon titre" } 
puts "hashManuel : "
puts hashManuel
```

where ./monFichier.yaml contains the following lines :

```
- enonce: "ma question"
  titre: "mon titre"
```

and the output is :

```
hashYaml : 
{"enonce"=>"ma question", "titre"=>"mon titre"}
hashManuel : 
{:enonce=>"ma question", :titre=>"mon titre"}
```

Can somebody please explain

1. why both lines are different ?
2. how I could obtain `hashYaml` in the same format as `hashManuel` ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109888/6543971), which I checked to be working.

It is to edit the Yaml file as follows :

```
- :enonce: "ma question"
  :titre: "mon titre"
```

Is there an other way that does not involve modifying my yaml file ? **Yes, see below**

**Edit : the answer I was looking for**

Adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890864/6543971)

So my Yaml file defines a table of hashes in Ruby. Say, it reads :

```
- enonce: "ma question facile"
  titre: "mon titre clair" 
- enonce: "ma question dure"
  titre: "mon titre obscur"
```

To import this file in Ruby as list of hashes whose keys are symbols, ie `{:myKey => "itsValue"}` *(what I meant by a **proper hash** before I knew the vocab)*
one may proceed as follows :

```
require 'yaml'

hashYaml = YAML::load_file('./monFichier.yaml')

hashYaml.each do |currentHash| # I am really working with a table of hash(es)
  currentHash.keys.each do |key|
    currentHash[(key.to_sym rescue key) || key] = currentHash.delete(key)
  end
end
```

Cheers,

Comment: Probably noteworthy that the inverse function to `YAML::load`, which is `YAML::dump` outputs the `:key: itsValue` convention in Yaml. This would push towards the first solution : editing the source Yaml file so as to have it consist of `:key: itsValue` assignments